# Scale/compress waveform sample data

Tags: javascript, sampling, waveform

I have an array with waveform sample data. The array must always be 512 bytes long, representing the waveform amplitude data.

When importing other waveform data arrays, they can be 477, 967 or 2020 bytes or whatever length. How can I convert for example 1456 bytes sample data to fit into 512 bytes and keep the waveform reasonably intact?

I tried some kind of scaling factor and interpolation but couldn't get it together.

Comment: This question is lacking technical context and is as much as "I want to do some things with some stuff." Can you provide some code that shows where you're at?

Comment: At it's simplest. divide your source samples in to 512 contiguous chunks, pick the maximum and minimum value from each of those chunks and calculate the difference between those two values. Presto... 512 measures of peak amplitude. EDIT: probably breaks down for shorter sets of samples.